# Adding Form To Dict With For Loop Confusion

Tags: django, python-2.7

I'm reading "Django By Example", in the "Online Store" chapter (6) and I'm a little confused by a simple piece of code in a view:

```
def cart_detail(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    for item in cart:
        item['update_quantity_form'] = CartAddProductForm(initial={'quantity': item['quantity'],'update': True})
    return render(request, 'cart/detail.html', {'cart': cart})
```

It obviously adds a form to each product in the cart, so the quantity can be updated (for each product in the cart). . .The Cart is simply a dict, saved in the session, which brings me to my question. . .

```
class Cart(object):
    def __init__(self, request):
        self.session = request.session
        cart = self.session.get(settings.CART_SESSION_ID)
        if not cart:
            # save an empty cart in the session
            cart = self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID] = {}
        self.cart= cart

    ...    
    def __iter__(self):
        """
        Iterate over the items in the cart and get the products from the database.
        """
        product_ids = self.cart.keys()
        # get the product objects and add them to the cart
        products = Product.objects.filter(id__in=product_ids)
        for product in products:
            self.cart[str(product.id)]['product'] = product

        for item in self.cart.values():
            item['price'] = Decimal(item['price'])
            item['total_price'] = item['price'] * item['quantity']
            yield item
```

In the **view** **for loop**, wouldn't trying to add `item ['update_quantity_form'] = CartAddProductForm(...)` to the cart which is a dict cause a type error? Something like `TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment`?

If I make a dict in IDLE to mimic a cart, `cart[1]={'quantity':30, 'price':15.00}` and `cart[2] = {'quantity':2, 'price':11.00}` then do `for item in cart: item['update_quantity_form']='form'` I obviously get a Type Error (like above).

So, I don't understand how his code in the book works. I realize I'm missing something very simple, but missing it nonetheless. Thanks in advance.

Edit: edited to add the Iter method, which I think may be the answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cart is stored as a `Cart` object, *not* as a simple `dict`. The overridden `__iter__` method causes the `for` loop to behave differently. Note the `yield item` at the end of method which will yield one of the `.values()` of the stored `dict`. So it is more or less equivalent to the following in IDLE:

```
>>> cart = {}
>>> cart[1] = {'quantity':30, 'price':15.00}
>>> cart[2] = {'quantity':2, 'price':11.00}
>>> for item in cart.values():
...     item['update_quantity_form'] = 'form'
...
>>> cart
```

which will work without errors and print

```
{1: {'price': 15.0, 'update_quantity_form': 'form', 'quantity': 30}, 
 2: {'price': 11.0, 'update_quantity_form': 'form', 'quantity': 2}}
```

Comment: Thank you! Yeah, I was just catching on to that, hence the edit. What confused me was overriding the __iter__ method, and not overriding __next__. Most examples I looked at, returned `self` in the iter method, and did the work in the next method. . .Again, thank you.